# User borders around LSP floating windows

Tags: neovim, lsp, floating-windows

In neovim, these keymaps (from [nvim-lspconfig](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig)) show diagnostics from LSP servers on a floating window:

```
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>le', vim.diagnostic.open_float, opts)
vim.keymap.set('n', '[d', vim.diagnostic.goto_prev, opts)
vim.keymap.set('n', ']d', vim.diagnostic.goto_next, opts)
```

The floating window uses highlight group `:h hl-NormalFloat`. I set its background to be equal to `:h hl-Normal` so it looks like a transparent window. The problem is: now I can't distinguish between the floating window and the main window.

I could reset the background color of `NormalFloat` to something distinguishable than `Normal`, but that would not work properly with the highlighting colors of the diagnostic messages. Adding a border around the floating would be the best solution. How do I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since version 5.0, neovim supports adding borders to floating windows. `:h lsp` integrates it, too. But not by default; we have to enable it. The following configuration would do so.

```lua
local _border = "single"

vim.lsp.handlers["textDocument/hover"] = vim.lsp.with(
  vim.lsp.handlers.hover, {
    border = _border
  }
)

vim.lsp.handlers["textDocument/signatureHelp"] = vim.lsp.with(
  vim.lsp.handlers.signature_help, {
    border = _border
  }
)

vim.diagnostic.config{
  float={border=_border}
}
```

The border of the floating windows uses `FloatBorder` highlight group. So we will have to define it for optimum readability/visibility.

```
highlight FloatBorder  ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE
```

The document for border can be found in `:h nvim_open_win` (search for `/\v<border:`), which is used in configuring LSP diagnostics (see `:h vim.diagnostic.config()`) and LSP handlers (see `:h vim.lsp.handlers.hover()` and `:h vim.lsp.handlers.signature_help()`).

P.S. The floating window of `:LSPInfo` does not use the configuration of the diagnostic or handlers. It's provided by the plugin nvim-lspconfig, which provides a separate configuration for its border, which can be activated by this code:

```lua
require('lspconfig.ui.windows').default_options = {
  border = _border
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the bit about `:LSPInfo`! That was the missing piece for me. Cheers!